# How to get rid of 'recent windows' section in macOS dock?

Tags: macos, big-sur, dock

Is it possible to totally get rid of the 'recent windows' dock section in macOS 11.6 Big Surr?

[image]

I've disabled 'Show recent applications in Dock' but it doesn't affect this dock section.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to see the *application* icons as shown in your first screen shot between the **Trash** and the *vertical bar* to the *left*, then check:

**[√] Minimize windows into application icon**

As shown in your second screen shot.

For any existing *windows* you need to un-minimize them and re-minimize them so the existing ones will no longer show.